# Azure Mobile Apps sync on background

Tags: android, azure, synchronization, offline

I'm currently using offline sync feature on an Android project.
It's posible to have a background process that sinchronize tables periodically without affecting user interaction?

For example, the user is inserting a new row on a table while the background process is synchronizing. This insertion is going to be held until the sync process gets done (i need to put a "wait please dialog")? or is going to be inserted anyway?

Thanks!